# Automapper - Access default map function in MapFrom to fallback

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm writing an extension method in order to do translation with Automapper.

I have some classes :

```cs
public class TranslatableClass : ITranslatable<TranslationClass>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<TranslationClass> Translations { get; set; }
    public string OtherEntityId { get; set; }
    public string OtherEntityLabel { get; set; }
    public List<OtherEntityTranslation> OtherEntityTranslations { get; set; }
}

public class TranslationClass : ITranslation
{
    public Guid LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class TranslatedClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string OtherEntityLabel { get; set; }
}

public class OtherEntityTranslation : ITranslation
{
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public Guid LanguageId { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to get an extension method like this one :

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<TranslatableClass, TranslatedClass>()
    .ForMember(t => t.OtherEntityLabel, opt => opt.MapFromTranslation(t => t.OtherEntityTranslations, oet => oet.Label));
```

And my extension method looks like this one

```cs
public static void MapFromTranslation<TSource, TDestination, TMember, TTranslation>(this IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource, TDestination, TMember> opt, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TTranslation>> getTranslations, Func<TTranslation, string> getValue)
    where TTranslation : ITranslation
{
    opt.MapFrom((src, _, _, context) =>
    {
        string result = null; // here is the pain point ; I'd like to get the value as if I was automapper 

        if (context.Options.Items.TryGetValue(LANGUAGE, out object contextLanguage) && contextLanguage is Guid languageId)
        {
            var translations = getTranslations(src);
            var translation = translations.FirstOrDefault(t => t.LanguageId == languageId);

            if (translation != null)
            {
                result = getValue(translation);
            }
        }

        return result;
    });
}
```

The issue I'm facing is I can't find a nice way to get the default behavior of AutoMapper when I don't have a translation. In this implementation, if I don't find a translation for my language, the value will be null while it should be the value of the source object (which is the default value).

I try to put PreCondition before the MapFrom but that doesn't map the property so I get null too.

I can try to get the value from the source object with reflexion but I will lose all the capabilities of Automapper like naming convention and other stuffs.

```cs
public static void MapFromTranslation<TSource, TDestination, TMember, TTranslation>(this IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource, TDestination, TMember> opt, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TTranslation>> getTranslations, Func<TTranslation, string> getValue)
    where TTranslation : ITranslation
{
    var destinationMember = opt.DestinationMember as PropertyInfo;

    var source = typeof(TSource);
    var sourceProperty = source.GetProperty(destinationMember.Name);

    if (sourceProperty != null)
    {
        opt.MapFrom((src, _, _, context) =>
        {
            string result = sourceProperty.GetValue(src) as string; // Get value from source as if it was the mapper 

            if (context.Options.Items.TryGetValue(LANGUAGE, out object contextLanguage) && contextLanguage is Guid languageId)
            {
                var translations = getTranslations(src);

                if (translations != null)
                {
                    var translation = translations.FirstOrDefault(t => t.LanguageId == languageId);

                    if (translation != null)
                    {
                        var value = getValue(translation);
                        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                        {
                            result = value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        });
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception($"Can't map property {opt.DestinationMember.Name} from {source.Name}");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need mapping inheritance.

Comment: How does it works ?

Comment: Check the docs. There are also many examples available online.

Answer (score 0):

Let's re-define configuration without using extension method, trying to simplify things. Following mapping example, we can implement custom IValueResolver

```
cfg.CreateMap<TranslatableClass, TranslatedClass>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.OtherEntityLabel, opt => opt.MapFrom<CustomResolver>();
```

Implementing `IValueResolver<TranslatableClass, TranslatedClass, string>` interface:

```
public class CustomResolver: IValueResolver<TranslatableClass, TranslatedClass, string>
{
    public string Resolve(TranslatableClass source, TranslatedClass destination, string member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        
        string result = source.Label;  /* needed effect! */ 

        /* can we simplify this condition? */
        if (context.Options.Items.TryGetValue(source.OtherEntityLabel, out object contextLanguage) 
            && contextLanguage is Guid languageId)
        {
            var translations = source.OtherEntityTranslations;
            var translation = translations.FirstOrDefault(t => t.LanguageId == languageId);

            if (translation != null)
            {
                result = translation.Label;
            };
        }
        
        return result;

    }

}
```

Here comes same logic from
`MapFromTranslation<TSource, TDestination, TMember, ...` extension method provided below, let's put that logic right - we map `TSource` as `TranslatableClass` to `TDestination` as `TranslatedClass`.

Also, I believe that `if (context.Options.Items.TryGetValue(...))` should be removed for simplicity too (are we trying to get `languageId` here?)

So, by using [`Custom Value Resolvers`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html) feature we can simplify mapper configuration and refactor for test coverage or debugging needs.

**Update**

> I do want to use this extensions method on 50 others entity and I
> won't write custom resolver for each one

Using Expressions instead of reflection should help to implement 'generic solution'. Solution is to define a cache of `mapping expressions` to access TSource and TDestination properties.

```
public static class MappingCache<TFirst, TSecond>
    {
        static MappingCache()
        {
            var first = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirst), "first");
            var second = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSecond), "second");

            var secondSetExpression = MappingCache.GetSetExpression(second, first);

            var blockExpression = Expression.Block(first, second, secondSetExpression, first);

            Map = Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirst, TSecond, TFirst>>(blockExpression, first, second).Compile();
        }

        public static Func<TFirst, TSecond, TFirst> Map { get; private set; }
    }
```

Next, let's try to define generic lambda-expressions for both
`Func<TTranslation, string> getValue` and `getTranslations(...`

e.g.:

```
        public static Expression GetSetExpression(ParameterExpression sourceExpression, params ParameterExpression[] destinationExpressions)
        {
         /** AutoMapper also can be used here */

         /* compile here all (source)=>(destination) expressions */

            var destination = destinationExpressions
                .Select(parameter => new
                {
                    Parameter = parameter,
                    Property =  parameter.Type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                        .FirstOrDefault(property => IsWritable(property) && IsOfType(property, sourceExpression.Type))
                })
                .FirstOrDefault(parameter => parameter.Property != null);

            if (destination == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("No writable property of type {0} found in types {1}.", sourceExpression.Type.FullName, string.Join(", ", destinationExpressions.Select(parameter => parameter.Type.FullName))));
            }

         /* Here is the generic version of mapping code! */

            return Expression.IfThen(
                Expression.Not(Expression.Equal(destination.Parameter, Expression.Constant(null))),
                Expression.Call(destination.Parameter, destination.Property.GetSetMethod(), sourceExpression));
        }
```

Next goes `IsWritable(PropertyInfo property)` that is used to check  validate properties, try to implement convention-based property filtering (names, attributes, etc.) here

```
        public static bool IsWritable(PropertyInfo property)
        {
/*  eliminating reflection code from extension method */
            return property.CanWrite && !property.GetIndexParameters().Any();

        }
```

Next `IsOfType(PropertyInfo...`  and `IsSubclassOf` methods, -  define simple rules of proper `TSource->TDestination` ways of mapping...

```
        public static bool IsOfType(PropertyInfo property, Type type)
        {
         /* here AutoMapper could be used too, making filtering needed destination entities by following some convention */ 
            return property.PropertyType == type || IsSubclassOf(type, property.PropertyType) || property.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(type);
        }

        public static bool IsSubclassOf(Type type, Type otherType)
        {
            return type.IsSubclassOf(otherType);
        }
    }
```

Trying to implement convention based mapping approach:

```
public static void MapFromTranslation<TSource, TDestination, TMember, TTranslation>(this IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource, TDestination, TMember> opt, Expression<Func<TSource, TDestination, TMember, TTranslation>> mapping )
    where TTranslation : ITranslation
```

Wiring around the `Expression<Func<TSource,TDestination,TMember, TTranslation> mapping` and the `MappingCache<TSource,TDestination,TMember, TTranslation>.Map` is the next step. Our lambda expression represents the property transformation intent generically (mapping,conversion,validating,navigating, etc...), and when compiled lambda called with parameters passed, we get the result of such transformation.

Expression:

```
MappingCache<TSource,TDestination,TMember, TTranslation>.GetSetExpression(first, second, third, proxy...
```

Function:

```
var result = MappingCache<TSource,TDestination,TMember, TTranslation>.Map(first,second,third,...
```

Keeping statically compiled lambda-delegates abstractions open, we can cover every needed mapping aspect with proper tests, - seems like the generic approach that could be used to address the question

> Access default map function in MapFrom to fallback

[(c) Dapper.Mapper](https://github.com/dotarj/Dapper.Mapper/)  + [Tests](http://blob/87c3cf09a720adbe7daf546d93278b0b3a18bac5/test/Dapper.Mapper.Tests/MappingCache2Tests.TheMapMethod.cs)

Comment: I want the solution to be as generic as possible. Using your solution will work only for TranslatableClass which I use only for unittesting my extension method. 
I do want to use this extensions method on 50 others entity and I won't write custom resolver for each one ^^.